# Lexical scope and Hoisting in javascript

Tags: javascript, hoisting

**Why below code gives error *TypeError***

I am reading javascript from book You-Dont-Know-JS. It should display 'b' as suggested in book.

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch4.md

```
<body>
 <script>
  foo(); // "b"
  var a = true;
  if (a) {
     function foo() { console.log( "b" ); }
   }
  else {
     function foo() { console.log( "b" ); }
   }

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Even if its possible: never ever declare functions inside a conditional branch

Comment: Function declarations in blocks are extremely weird and have changed behaviours between ES3 and ES5 (and don’t behave as specified in either of those in IE8 and earlier!). You don’t really need to know how they worked before because there’s no reason to ever write code like that.

Answer (score 1):

Short version: YDKJS seems to be out of date here. The behavior of functions inside blocks changed in ES6. In ES6, those functions are scoped to their enclosing block, as if they were declared with `let`. Prior to ES6, functions inside blocks weren't even legal.

Longer version:

Function declarations used to be illegal anywhere except at the top-level of a scope.

In [ES5](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-A.4), a statement included things like var statements, if statements, return statements... but not function declarations. Instead, there is a "source element" that is either a statement or a function declaration, and the program itself and function bodies were defined to be 0 or more source elements. So a function declaration could appear at the top-level of a program, or at the top-level inside another function, but not inside blocks (if blocks, for blocks, etc).

Contrasted with [ES6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-statements) and beyond, where function declarations still aren't technically a statement, but they can appear in statement *lists*, since a statement list item is either a statement or a declaration, and functions inside blocks are considered a lexical (not a hoistable) declaration.